# Want To Capture Fragment URL on a SPA

Tags: google-analytics

I want to be able to capture the full URL on a single page application SPA and that includes the hashtag. My GA tracking code is below. It’s capturing the full URL including the #index for the home page but when I click on the About button for example the URL that gets sent to GA doesn’t change. The url should now end with #about. The tracking code is below. How do I fix this so that when they click the other buttons the URL changes.

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-XX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
 
  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXX-XX', {'page_path': location.pathname + location.hash});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following to your routing:

```
gtag('event', 'page_view',{'page_path': location.pathname + location.hash});
```

Comment: Do I add that to each menu button?

Comment: still not understanding this.  Can you finish helping me?

Comment: I believe I have a solution; can you confirm that this is a good way to go about it, on each menu button onclick="javascript:window.location.href='http://www.example.com/testchangetitle.html#home'; myView()"

Comment: the function is what you gave me before;           function myView(){
 gtag('event', 'page_view',{'page_path': location.pathname + location.hash});
 
}

Comment: I'm not familiar with sharepoint and even more so with how your particular site works. I think the piece of code should be applied within the functions you have to change the screen/view in your SPA, not on the clicks of menu items.